# PHP Search Relevant Results

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck with a case. I want a search be done where if the user made some spelling mistake it will search the mysql database and return a result like 'Did You Mean *something*'. I have went through the levenshtein method, but it does not return the expected result. 
For example if I search for "chicken" in an array of items like 'apple', 'bean' , 'chicken soup' ; it returns me bean . Is there a better way to solve this? I am using PHP MYSQL to achieve this functionality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relevant search results from a MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646454/relevant-search-results-from-a-mysql-table)

Comment: You will want to provide some examples of what you have tried or your example of levenshteins distance not working.

Comment: Search is a very complex topic. You may want to look into a dedicated search server such as Solr.

Comment: Or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Comment: @sixeightzero: Take a look at the code for example( got from php.net)
[link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Look at example 1. If you make the input term to 'chicken' and add an extra array item ; lets say 'chicken soup', it returns 'pea', bean , etc. But not 'chicken soup'

Answer (score 0):

Although Levensteins distance should do the trick, have you looked into [`similar_text()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) or [`soundex()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php).

I've used `similar_text` for something similar, as it can return a percentage of similarity between matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Soundex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) which based pronunciation "pronounced similarly produce the same soundex key".

To get much better results, First get set of words with minimum distance(say 2 or 3) then apply soundex on filtered set of words to get suggested words. I implemented in one of my past project, works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend MySQL full-text searching.
You can find more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

The syntax you want to be using is `MATCH() ... AGAINST`.
Be sure to use tables of the type MyISAM and to create indexes on the fields you want to search in.

Hope this helps,

Bram

Comment: Hi Bram, Full text searching was implemented previously but its does not handle the typing mistakes. So looking for something else